# Limiting the extent of text selection (not completely) in a HTML page

Tags: html, css, iframe, textselection

I am attempting to make it difficult for nefarious users to copy user content (poems, greeting messages, etc.) displayed on a webpage. Unfortunately I cannot use the well-known CSS selector `user-select: none` because this prevents all text selection and it has been rejected by our users as "too aggressive".

For this frustrating reason I am wanting to simulate the behaviour of text selection when an iframe is embedded in the HTML. When a user begins selecting content in the parent frame they are unable to continue the selection into the iframe content during a single action. This behaviour is well documented in Firefox and is likely shared by other browsers.

Obviously this will only slow down any nefarious actors however if I could somehow apply this behaviour to each line of text then I believe it is a step in the right direction.

My question is can this behaviour be mimicked without using iframes?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why not simply use a `.selective-no-select { user-select: none }` class and protect only the text that needs protecting? Anyway, a simple right click will still unveil any code, including iframes. 'Absolute Enable Right Click & Copy' extension will override any custom right click menu...